# Permission for java applet to be used on web browser

Tags: java

I have created an applet that I would like to run on web browser. The applet contains features  such as sending an email and opening another applet using URI.

The interface works fine. However,

these parts seem to need a permission.

```
...........................................................
    //creating session
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

    // to add recipients 
    InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.size()];

    // To get the array of recipients addresses
    for( int i=0; i < to.size(); i++ ) { 
        toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println(Message.RecipientType.TO);

    //adding recipients
    for( int i=0; i < toAddress.length; i++) { 
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
    }
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText("This is Zaid's app");


   // check if animation was selected
    if(animation)
     fileName= attachment +".gif";
    else
     fileName = attachment +".JPEG";

    //add the attachment
    MimeBodyPart attachMent = new MimeBodyPart();
    FileDataSource dataSource= new FileDataSource(new File("ScaryImages//"+ fileName));
    attachMent.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource));
    attachMent.setFileName(fileName);
    attachMent.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(attachMent);
    message.setContent(multipart);


    //this is the sender variable
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");

    //trying to send...
    try{
    System.out.println("connecting...");
    transport.connect(host, from, pass);

    System.out.println("sending...Please wait...");
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
    System.out.println("sent");

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Email has been sent successfully!");
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //exception handling, the problem is mainly the connection
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Connection Problem has been detected! Please Try again.");
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);

    }

    //remove loading label anyway
    finally{

        EmailApplet.removeLoadingLabel();
    }
   .......................
```

also this,

try {

```
        java.net.URI uri = new java.net.URI( arg );
        desktop.browse( uri );
    }
```

Can you please tell me what permission and where should I provide? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a new page, in another tab or window, try this:

```
getAppletContext().showDocument(url.toURI(), "_blank");
```

**"_self"** Show in the window and frame that contain the applet.
**"_parent"** Show in the applet's parent frame. If has no parent frame, acts the same as "_self".
**"_top"**  Show in the top-level frame of the applet's window. If the applet's frame is the top-level frame, acts the same as "_self".
**"_blank"**    Show in a new, unnamed top-level window.